# Improve Android battery life by lowering CPU freq

Tags: battery-life

I would like to know if it could be possible to use [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) (Android Debug Bridge) to tell the phone to lower its CPU max freq.

I'd like to use less battery if possible, and in my use case I don't mind if some tasks are a little slower.

Comment: You might want to check out this article from How-To Geek on methods to reduce battery usage before you do something as extreme as underclocking your CPU. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25319/complete-guide-to-maximizing-your-android-phones-battery-life/

Comment: I've read this barely impacts your phone but produces extremely impressive results. As long as he's already rooted, this isn't that extreme.

Answer (score 5):

There is a program called **SetCPU** which will allow you to over/under clock the processor.  The advantage here is the ability to set profiles to have the phone determine when to adjust the processor, such as when the phone is at a certain temprature, or if it's plugged in or not.

I've been using it on my Droid Eris for a while now, and the results have been great.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was looking for, but I need to do it manually or to implement it in my own application.  Any idea in that sense is welcome.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't help you there, however these guys can, http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=524

Comment: This requires root to use.

Comment: @colithium Yes, you've got to root, but considering that he was planning to use ADB to try to adjust the cpu, rooted was a given.

Comment: Just for community reference ;)